# Скачивается пустой PDF файл JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, async-await, redux

Добрый день!

Суть проблемы описана в заголовке.

Сейчас у меня из React компонента по клику действие передается в action, где у меня идет запрос к backend'у при помощи async-await. Затем, если всё ок, то я в dispatch передаю response.data (мой pdf), затем при помощи хелпера, создаю невидимую ссылку, кликаю на нее и файл скачивается, но он пустой. Проверялось на разных файлах, везде качивается pdf файл с пустыми страницами (замечу, что страниц столько же, сколько и в документе реальном). Подозрение, что что-то не так с кодировками, но найти ошибку не могу. Реализовываю такое впервые, поэтому в тупике и не знаю как найти выход из данной проблемы.

Вот мой код:

Мой Action

```
export const request = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF);
export const success = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF_SUCCESS, ({ response, id }) => {
    fileDownload(response, `return-${id}.pdf`); // Мой хелпер
    return { payload: { data: response, id } };
});
export const failure = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF_FAIL);

export default ({ id }) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            dispatch(request());
            const response = await returns.getPdf({ id });
            dispatch(success({ response: response.data, id }));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(
                failure({
                    payload: {
                        message: 'Неудалось скачать PDF',
                        stack: error.stack,
                    },
                }),
            );
            errorLogger(error, DOWNLOAD_PDF);
        }
    };
};
```

Мой хелпер:

```
export default function (data, fileName, format = 'utf-8') {
    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        const byteNumbers = new Array(data.length); // save file in IE or edge
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            byteNumbers[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: format });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        return;
    }

    let url = `data:application/pdf;charset=${format}`;
    if (format === 'windows-1251') {
        url += `;base64,${btoa(data)}`;
    } else {
        url += `,${encodeURIComponent(data)}`;
    }
    const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    tempLink.href = url;
    tempLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
    tempLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
}
```

Любая помощь будет очень ценной!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, нашлось решение. Ходил вокруг него много раз.

Проблема крылась в том, что у меня есть отдельный файл, который создает в запросе свои header и httpConfig'и и надо было лишь добавить туда responseType: 'blob'

Вот так

```
export const getPdfConfig = axios.create({
    ...httpConfig,
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
        ...customHeaders,
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    },
}).get;
```

Ну а затем использовать fileSaver.